# Obtener json de una rest api y mostrarlo en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, rest

tengo esta rest api que me devuelve nombres de una base de datos. El tema es que he intentado varias formas de mostrarlo en AngularJS y no he conseguido hacerlo.

Url de la respuesta .json

```
http://samp.newclan.com.uy:3000/api/names
```

AngularJS

```js
var app = angular.module('adminPanel', []);

app.controller('namesController', function($scope) {
    $http.get("http://samp.newclan.com.uy:3000/api/names")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
});
```

Respuesta Json

```
[{"nombre":"Example_example"},{"nombre":"Sebastian_Treend"},{"nombre":"Jose_Martinez"},{"nombre":"Demo_Demo"}]
```

Cual seria la mejor forma de devolver correctamente estos nombres en el scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo con tus datos, pruebalo:

```js
<script>
var app = angular.module('adminPanel', []);
app.controller('namesController', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("http://samp.newclan.com.uy:3000/api/names")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="adminPanel">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ej de AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="namesController">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in names">
                   <td>{{data.nombre}}</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Si al abrir la página no muestra los datos, presiona F12, si tienes éste error:

```html
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://samp.newclan.com.uy:3000/api/names. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Entonces es por problemas de CORS, que ya sería un tema aparte del navegador que deberías investigar o consultar de nuevo.

Saludos

PD: Dejo captura del funcionamiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD 2: jejeje

analizando tu código de hace rato:

```html
 <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in names">
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.country}}</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Tu error está en que ng-repeat="data in names" está dentro del primer tr que corresponde al head, pero en el body esos datos no están presente, debería ser alrevez.

```html
 <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr >
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in names">
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>{{data.name}}</td>
              <td>{{data.country}}</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Espero sirva la respuesta.
Bye..

Comment: En respuesta a tu PD2 eso es viejo jaja ya me di cuenta y lo arregle, pero gracias :p y si definitivamente me da este error XMLHttpRequest cannot load :(

Answer (score 1):

aquí tienes un ejemplo funcionando que hace lo que necesitas:

```
                                                            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ej de AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6" ng-app="adminPanel" ng-controller="namesController">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="data in names">
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">var app = angular.module('adminPanel', []);

app.controller('namesController', function($scope, $http) {

var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$http.get(root + "/users")
    .then(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response.data;
    });
});</script>
```